# Repairing DBCC CHECKDB errors. Restore did not work.

Tags: sql-server

Hey everyone I am having some issues with my sql server database. It appears that the automated backups where not functioning properly and a restore did not fix my issue. I ran a CHECKDB and it spit out the following errors.
LOG FILE:

```
Warnings: --->
W (1): CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 10 consistency errors 
not associated with any single object.
    W (2): CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 24 consistency errors 
in table 'details' (object ID 1853926372).
    W (3): CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 34 consistency errors 
in database 'NIX'.
    W (4): repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the 
errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (PHOENIX).
           <---
  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
359574662873088 (type Unknown), page (3584:587202560). Test (IS_OFF 
(BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -14.
  Msg: 8939, Level: 16, State: 98, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
24488610741813248 (type Unknown), page ID (1:233390215) contains an 
incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = 
(78:4784160).
  Msg: 8909, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
27866160140386304 (type Unknown), page ID (1:233390212) contains an 
incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = 
(100:6488096).
  Msg: 8909, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
28147708131803136 (type Unknown), page ID (1:233390207) contains an 
incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = 
(2816:2052).
  Msg: 8909, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
28147914284990464 (type Unknown), page ID (1:233390134) contains an 
incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = 
(78:5111881).
  Msg: 8909, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
31244194867511296 (type Unknown), page ID (1:233390211) contains an 
incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = 
(79:5374022).
  Msg: 8909, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
5620492349504225280 (type Unknown), page (83:796). Test (IS_OFF 
(BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -1.
  Msg: 8939, Level: 16, State: 98, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
6341348650819518464 (type Unknown), page (76:4522067). Test (IS_OFF 
(BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -1.
  Msg: 8939, Level: 16, State: 98, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
7133761184305512448 (type Unknown), page (0:525312). Test (IS_OFF 
(BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -1.
  Msg: 8939, Level: 16, State: 98, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 
7205835271219183616 (type Unknown), page (28160:1728080128). Test 
(IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -1.
  Msg: 8939, Level: 16, State: 98, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 72059003269808128, 
alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data): Page (1:233390133) 
could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
  Msg: 8928, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 
72059003269808128, alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data). 
Page (1:233390133) was not seen in the scan although its parent 
(1:233383837) and previous (1:233390132) refer to it. Check any previous 
errors.
  Msg: 8976, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 72059003269808128, 
alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data): Page (1:233390134) 
could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
  Msg: 8928, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 
72059003269808128, alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data). 
Index node page (1:233383837), slot 98 refers to child page 
(1:233390134) and previous child (1:233390133), but they were not 
encountered.
  Msg: 8980, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 72059003269808128, 
alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data): Page (1:233390135) 
could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
  Msg: 8928, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 
72059003269808128, alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data). 
Index node page (1:233383837), slot 99 refers to child page 
(1:233390135) and previous child (1:233390134), but they were not 
encountered.
  Msg: 8980, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 
72059003269808128, alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data). 
Page (1:233390136) is missing a reference from previous page 
(1:233390135). Possible chain linkage problem.
  Msg: 8978, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 72059003269808128, 
alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data): Page (1:233390206) 
could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
  Msg: 8928, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 
72059003269808128, alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data). 
Page (1:233390206) was not seen in the scan although its parent 
(1:233383837) and previous (1:233390205) refer to it. Check any previous 
errors.
  Msg: 8976, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 72059003269808128, 
alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data): Page (1:233390207) 
could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
  Msg: 8928, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

  Table error: Object ID 1853926372, index ID 1, partition ID 
72059003269808128, alloc unit ID 72059273826074624 (type In-row data). 
Index node page (1:233383837), slot 171 refers to child page 
(1:233390207) and previous child (1:233390206), but they were not 
encountered.
  Msg: 8980, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1
```

Most of the places I see this issue recommend a restore but again that did not work for me.
Any suggestions on how to repair the corrupt table would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This should be on http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Your database does not have checksums enabled. That's not good either. Make yourself familiar with proper backup and restore procedures asap.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing a rebuild on the indexes by doing the following inside of SQL Server Management Studio:

1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server
   Database Engine and then expand that instance.
2. Expand Databases, expand the database that contains the table with
   the specified index, and then expand Tables.
3. Expand the table in which the index belongs and then expand Indexes.
4. Right-click the index to rebuild and then click Rebuild.
5. To start the rebuild operation, click OK.

Steps from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187874(v=sql.105).aspx

It took a little bit of time but did the trick.

Comment: Table I was having issues with had 6 indexes.  I did this and it ran fine for 5 of the 6 but errored out on one. The one it errored out on, I dropped and recreated the index.  DBCC CheckDb ran fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
exec msforeachtable 
    'Select *
    Into Alternate_db.?
    From ?'
```

to get data out of database.
into another database.
then use RedGate Sql Compare , and synchronize Structure with last backup you are taken.